# How to generate and output the smallest random number from a list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

///before

```
let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100+1)
let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100+1)
let c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100+1)
const abc = [a,b,c]
result = Math.min(...abc);
console.log(result)// works!
```

///after

```
function test() {
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100+1)
  let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100+1)
  let c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100+1)
  let abc = [];
if((a==!b)&&(b==!c)){
   abc.push(a);
   abc.push(b);
   abc.push(c);
   const num = Math.min(...abc);
   console.log(num);
   
  } else{  
  a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100+1)
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100+1)
  c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100+1)
      }
}
 //return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //최댓값도 포함, 최솟값도 포함

test();
```

Hey, friends! I've tried to create a function that selects three random numbers from 1 to 100 and outputs the smallest number. Could you please help me identify any issues in my code?
I wrote this code to select non-repeating numbers, but it's not working
:( help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function selectSmallestNumber() {
  var numbers = [];
  
  // Generate three random numbers and add them to the list
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; // Random number between 1 and 100
    numbers.push(randomNumber);
  }
  
  // Find the smallest number in the list
  var smallestNumber = Math.min(...numbers);
  
  return smallestNumber;
}

var result = selectSmallestNumber();
console.log(result);
```

In this code, the selectSmallestNumber function initializes an empty array numbers. It then generates three random numbers between 1 and 100 using Math.random() and Math.floor() functions and adds them to the numbers array using the push method.

To find the smallest number in the array, the Math.min() function is used along with the spread operator ... to spread the numbers from the array as individual arguments.

Finally, the smallest number is returned from the function and printed to the console using console.log().

When you run this code, it will select three random numbers and output the smallest one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets,arrays but with uniqe things

```js
var abc = new Set([]);

while(abc.size != 3){
   abc.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101));
}

console.log(Math.min(...Array.from(abc.values())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop

```js
function test() {
  let abc = [];
  while (abc.length < 3) {
    let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    if (!abc.includes(n)) abc.push(n);
  }
  return Math.min(...abc);
}
```